# How to configure web project to find jars in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a maven project from the command line, which contained dependencies to hibernate jars. Then I converted to an eclipse project (mvn eclipse:eclipse) and was able to get a hibernate example working.

Then I converted the project to a dynamic web project for tomcat within eclipse.  I can run a servlet within the project, but I can't access the hibernate api since the hibernate jars are not in the WEB-INF/lib.

What is the preferred way to copy the jars there within eclipse, or alternatvively (preferably) to configure references to the jars that are in the maven repository (in order to avoid copying large jar files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add Maven Dependencies to Deployment

> Project Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path
>   Entries > Maven Dependencies

- Add Maven Dependencies to Build Path

> Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Maven
>   Dependencies

Comment: Thanks. I think the first action you indicated was all that's necessary? (since the 2nd action is a duplicate of the first action)